# Unity3d + Google Play Games Проблемы авторизации

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, google-play-services

Проблема с гугл плей сервисами, создал приложение, связал его с сервисом, делаю лидерборд, все выпустил и приложение и сервис, но не могу авторизоваться в приложении. Создал пустой проект в юнити все равно не могу авторизоваться, вот код. В чем может быть проблема

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public Text text;    
    void Start () {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private void OnGUI() {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0,150,150),"Enter")) {
            Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
            {
                if (success) {
                   text.text = "You've successfully logged in" + Social.localUser.userName;
                } else {
                   text.text = "Login failed for some reason";
                }
            });
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0,150,150,150),"Send")) {
            Social.ReportScore(10,"CgkI2qbas9ANEAIQAQ",(bool success) =>
            {
                if (success) {
                    ( (PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active ).ShowLeaderboardUI("CgkI2qbas9ANEAIQAQ");
                } else {
                    //Debug.Log("Login failed for some reason");
                }
            });
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0,300,150,150),"Show")) {
            Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ты пытаешься проверить внутри unity editor?  На устройстве проверял?

Comment: да, на устройстве только и пробую, фишка в том что у меня появляется окно типо, гугл геймс идет загрузка и все, не пишет типо "Добро пожаловать " и ник

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Что-то я у вас инициализации не вижу. У вас в коде только `PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();` вызывается.

Вы точно [этот](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#configuration--initialization-play-game-services) пункт реализовали у себя?

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
```

Если всё ещё не будет работать, попробуйте аутентификацию явно из библиотеки вызывать:

`PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate`.